# AddThis in Joomla Category Blog Override. Linking to corresponding articles

Tags: php, joomla, blogs, addthis, custom-url

I've overwritten the "blog.php", for Category Blog to put the AddThis social media sharing plugin at the bottom of each article. Working on joomla 3.0

The Category blog layout displays many articles per page. By default AddThis uses your current page to share/like/tweet/etc.

My add this code looks like this:

```
<div class="article-sharing">
    <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
    <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
        <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
        <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=undefined"></script>
    <!-- AddThis Button END -->
</div>
```

What I of course want is to change the URL being used to the corresponding article. This is possible (http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381242-url-title#.Ucd1HevmT2x).

The code should look like this (only with dynamic urls):

```
<div class="article-sharing">
    <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
    <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style"
        addthis:url="http://example.com/blog/my-article-about-horses"
        addthis:title="The title of my article"
        addthis:description="The short article description">
        <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
        <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=undefined"></script>
    <!-- AddThis Button END -->
</div>
```

Would be great if someone could help me understand a bit better how I go about doing this.

```
addthis:url="http://example.com/blog/my-article-about-horses"
addthis:title="The title of my article"
addthis:description="The short article description"
```

Here is the full blog.php code.

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  com_content
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2012 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

JHtml::addIncludePath(JPATH_COMPONENT.'/helpers');

JHtml::_('behavior.caption');
?>
<div class="blog<?php echo $this->pageclass_sfx;?>">
   <?php if ($this->params->get('show_page_heading', 1)) : ?>
   <div class="page-header">
      <h1> <?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('page_heading')); ?> </h1>
   </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($this->params->get('show_category_title', 1) or $this->params->get('page_subheading')) : ?>
   <h2> <?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('page_subheading')); ?>
      <?php if ($this->params->get('show_category_title')) : ?>
      <span class="subheading-category"><?php echo $this->category->title;?></span>
   <?php endif; ?>
</h2>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($this->params->get('show_description', 1) || $this->params->def('show_description_image', 1)) : ?>
   <div class="category-desc">
      <?php if ($this->params->get('show_description_image') && $this->category->getParams()->get('image')) : ?>
      <img src="<?php echo $this->category->getParams()->get('image'); ?>"/>
   <?php endif; ?>
   <?php if ($this->params->get('show_description') && $this->category->description) : ?>
   <?php echo JHtml::_('content.prepare', $this->category->description, '', 'com_content.category'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="clr"></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $leadingcount = 0; ?>
<?php if (!empty($this->lead_items)) : ?>
   <div class="items-leading">
      <?php foreach ($this->lead_items as &$item) : ?>
      <div class="leading-article leading-<?php echo $leadingcount; ?><?php echo $item->state == 0 ? ' system-unpublished' : null; ?>">
         <?php
         $this->item = &$item;
         echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
         ?>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <?php
      $leadingcount++;
      ?>
<div class="article-sharing">
   <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
   <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style"
   addthis:url="http://example.com"
   addthis:title="An Example Title"
   addthis:description="An Example Description">
   <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
   <a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
   <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=undefined"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</div><!-- end items-leading -->
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
$introcount = (count($this->intro_items));
$counter = 0;
?>
<?php if (!empty($this->intro_items)) : ?>
   <?php foreach ($this->intro_items as $key => &$item) : ?>
   <?php
   $key = ($key - $leadingcount) + 1;
   $rowcount = (((int) $key - 1) % (int) $this->columns) + 1;
   $row = $counter / $this->columns;

   if ($rowcount == 1) : ?>
   <div class="items-row cols-<?php echo (int) $this->columns;?> <?php echo 'row-'.$row; ?> row-fluid">
   <?php endif; ?>
   <div class="span<?php echo round((12 / $this->columns));?>">
      <div class="item column-<?php echo $rowcount;?><?php echo $item->state == 0 ? ' system-unpublished' : null; ?>">
         <?php
         $this->item = &$item;
         echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
         ?>
         <div class="article-sharing">
            <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
            <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
               <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
               <a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
               <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=undefined"></script>
            <!-- AddThis Button END -->
         </div>
         
      </div><!-- end item -->
      <?php $counter++; ?>
   </div><!-- end spann -->
   <?php if (($rowcount == $this->columns) or ($counter == $introcount)): ?>         
</div><!-- end row -->
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if (!empty($this->link_items)) : ?>
   <div class="items-more older-articles">
      <?php echo $this->loadTemplate('links'); ?>
   </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (!empty($this->children[$this->category->id])&& $this->maxLevel != 0) : ?>
   <div class="cat-children">
      <h3> <?php echo JTEXT::_('JGLOBAL_SUBCATEGORIES'); ?> </h3>
      <?php echo $this->loadTemplate('children'); ?> </div>
   <?php endif; ?>
   <?php if (($this->params->def('show_pagination', 1) == 1  || ($this->params->get('show_pagination') == 2)) && ($this->pagination->get('pages.total') > 1)) : ?>
   <div class="pagination">
      <?php  if ($this->params->def('show_pagination_results', 1)) : ?>
      <!-- <p class="counter pull-right hidden-phone"> <?php echo $this->pagination->getPagesCounter(); ?> </p> -->
   <?php endif; ?>
   <?php echo $this->pagination->getPagesLinks(); ?> </div>
<?php  endif; ?>
</div>
```

---

## Update

Thank you Ahmad for your answer. It helped out a lot.

This is my current AddThis code within the blog_item.php file. It works well for Twitter, email etc. But I have some issues when it comes to Facebook. The "addthis:title" and description are being not being used. Instead the OG tags I have in the index.php file are being used. It still links to the correct article when the shared link is clicked on Facebook. This can be a bit confusing for the user - when he/she get's the Facebook share pop-up there is nothing about the article that he/she wants to share - only info about the page in general.

```
<div class="article-sharing">
    <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
    <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style"
    addthis:url="http://www.tolt-inspiration.com<?php echo JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($this->item->slug, $this->item->catid)); ?>"
    addthis:title="<?php echo $this->escape($this->item->title); ?>"
    addthis:description="<?php echo $this->escape($this->item->metadesc); ?>">
    <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"
    addthis:title="<?php echo $this->escape($this->item->title); ?>"
    addthis:description="<?php echo $this->escape($this->item->metadesc); ?>"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
    <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
</div>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
</div>
```

How to fix that?

Comment: I was randomly checking the post when I found that you made some edits. If you want to *notify* users about your update it would be great that you post a comment as a reply to my answer. This way I get notified that you updated the question and be able to see and help you. Take sometime to review the help section on Stackoverflow =) to get the maximum benefit from the website. I will review your update and update my answer as well.

Comment: As regard the Facebook issue, you can test to see if the current view is an article, don't echo the OG tags you added to your index.php and instead the addthis tags will be used. If you're facing troubles doing that I could happily post the code.

Comment: Thanks again Ahmad. I didn't quite understand the facebook OG part. Could you you go into a few more details on that?

Comment: How do you include the facebook OG part in your template?

Answer (score 0):

#### Note on editing core files

<strike>First of all let's clarify that editing Joomla's core file is a bad practice. You should always [use overrides](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core). This way you make sure that your changes wont get overwritten when Joomla is updated.</strike>

**update:** didn't notice the question title saying that OP is working on override already.

## How Joomla category view is rendered

Let's dissect the category view in Joomla (in order of execution). It starts with *default.php* (mother of all views) Then either loads:

1. blog.php (*for blog view; obviously*) This part output the category description, image, title, columns ... etc and will call the following parts:

   1. blog_item.php -- display the article **<- This is the file you should be working on.**
   2. blog_links.php
2. default_items.php (*for list view*)

For **Joomla 1.5** before `<span class="article_separator">&nbsp;</span>` add the code

For **Joomla 2.5** before `<div class="item-separator"></div>` add the code

### The code

```
<div class="article-sharing">
   <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
   <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style"
   addthis:url="<?php echo $this->item->readmore_link; ?>"
   addthis:title="<?php echo $this->escape($this->item->title); ?>"
   addthis:description="<?php echo $this->escape($this->item->metadesc); ?>">
   <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
   <a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
   <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
</div>
```

### Adding the `<script>`

Note that now we didn't add [addthis](/questions/tagged/addthis) `<script>` yet. You don't want to be adding it to `blog_item.php` or it will be added multiple times. We will add it to `blog.php`. To add it [using Joomla's API](http://docs.joomla.org/JDocument/addScript):

Right after:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
```

Add:

```
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScript("//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=undefined");
```

**Note**

Adding the script using the `addScript` method is not required but it is preferred than just adding it simply in the template. Some plugins for example move every script tag right before closing the body tag; It provides a way to grasp that object.